# Perfect DMZ: LDAP auth to AD

Tags: authentication, firewalls, active-directory, ldap, dmz

My goal is to integrate a public facing service with AD using LDAP.
While I vouch for federated approach to user authentication, the business dictates LDAP.

We run a DMZ subnet and I insist on not punching any(punching as few as possible) holes towards LAN, however the microsoft way is mockery of the DMZ concept. Assuming the best strategy is to place a Read-Only Domain Controller into DMZ, their document lists a number of ports that need to be opened for RODC -> LAN ([RO required ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd728028(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#required-communication-ports)).
Our original plan was to put RODC into DMZ segment and target it with our LDAP connector from an application server.

Is there a known solution for one way replication of AD user subset towards DMZ RODC\other LDAP capable server, or a configuration for RODC that doesn't allow any connections towards writable DC?

Comment: The link you mentioned in your question is returning 404

Comment: @safesploit thanks, amended

Answer (score 1):

Your security concerns are definitely valid, and you're correct in wanting to limit the number of open ports between your DMZ and internal LAN as much as possible. It's a best practice to limit the attack surface area.

One possible solution to your problem is to set up an LDAP Proxy in the DMZ which can forward your requests to the AD server in your LAN. This way, you would only need to open a single port from your DMZ to your LAN for LDAP or LDAPS (LDAP Secure). LDAPS would be recommended as it will encrypt your LDAP traffic.

This setup would look like this:

Public Facing Service -> LDAP Proxy (DMZ) -> AD (LAN)

It's important to note that this approach still allows a potential attacker who has compromised your LDAP proxy to send arbitrary requests to your AD server, but the attack surface is significantly smaller than opening multiple ports for an RODC. This is because the LDAP Proxy will be able to handle only LDAP-related requests and not the other types of traffic that a RODC would require.

The other option is to use an RODC in the DMZ but to carefully configure the firewall to allow only the necessary traffic. It's true that the Microsoft documentation lists a number of ports that need to be open, but it might be possible to limit this by carefully analyzing the actual needs of your RODC and the specifics of your network configuration. This would require a careful risk analysis and perhaps involve some trial and error.

Another option is to use a third-party solution that could sit in your DMZ and synchronise with your AD. There are products available that can do this (Microsoft Forefront Identity Manager (FIM) / Microsoft Identity Manager (MIM) and Okta Universal Directory), but they come with their own set of trade-offs, including cost and additional complexity.

In the end, the solution you choose will depend on your specific needs and the security risks that you're willing to accept. Each option has its own trade-offs and requires a careful risk analysis. Be sure to consider all your options and choose the one that best fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for input, the solution you mention as LDAP proxy is not what I seek, as it still exposes a LAN port inbound. Do you mind expanding a little on FIM/MIM in particular any keywords that I can use to find the configuration that matches my request, please? I didn't quite grasp the approach looking at MS site for MIM.

Comment: @GrigorySergeev sure I've tried to format this better for the comment section, but I suspect it may come across wordy.

Overview of MIM:
MIM is Microsoft's tool designed for identity management which manages identity synchronisation, certificate management, and user password resets. The core functionality that would be of interest is its ability to synchronise identity data.

Key Concepts to Understand:
1.MIM Synchronisation Service
2.MIM Service and Portal
3.Connector/Management Agent in MIM
4.Run Profile
5.Metaverse
6.Provisioning and Deprovisioning
7. MIM Service Account

Comment: A Few Parting Thoughts for MIM:
- Test this setup thoroughly in a controlled environment before implementing.
-The communication between MIM and the LDAP server in DMZ should be encrypted.
-Keep an eye on the synchronization logs for any unusual activity.

Comment: Given your concerns are about exposing internal ports, especially LDAP, another viable strategy you might consider is to use AD Federation Services (AD FS).

Benefits of AD FS:
- No Direct AD Exposure
- Standard-based
- Fine-grained control.
Leveraging AD FS and its proxy capability, you can achieve a secure authentication mechanism without exposing internal ports or directly exposing your AD to external systems.

Comment: Cheers for your effort, but I'm afraid we have digressed considerably. My original hope was to find that one-way sync magic, but it seems I will have to accept a "No" for an answer. I'd be happy to accept your alternatives if you could amend the answer a little, to state there's no known solution for one way comminucation LAN->DMZ and maybe list the alternatives you mentioned in comments (federation was out of scope)